# SQL insert row and increment others

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm wanting to insert a row and increment a value in all other rows after. Is there a way to do this in a single sql insert?

```
id |  value
------------
a  |  0
b  |  1
c  |  2
```

Inserting d | 2 should make the DB look like this:

```
id |  value
------------
a  |  0
b  |  1
d  |  2
c  |  3
```

Comment: I don't think so, You should first select all rows with value greather than the value You want to insert, increment every single row, and finnaly insert new row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with [George Vremescu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584377/george-vremescu). [`AFTER INSERT TRIGGER`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) sounds like the way to go.

```
CREATE TRIGGER <triggername> AFTER  
INSERT ON <tablename> WHEN 
(
   -- Update logic here
)
```

To get the last inserted row ID you should use [`last_insert_row()`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

Answer (score 4):

You could try creating a before insert trigger that will update the old values accordingly. Does your database support triggers?

Comment: Using sqlite on Android, a quick Google looks like they're supported